# Does postgres automatically generate an id for every row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres and SQL in general. I am coming from NoSQL. More specific mongodb. In mongodb every document had a unique id automatically generated by mongodb.

Do postgres rows automatically have a unique id or do you have to generate them yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define one for yourself:

```
create table foo
(
  id integer generated always as identity primary key,
  .... other columns
);
```

In a relational database you have to define the primary key yourself, the database does not make assumptions about that. e.g. a link table for a many-to-many relationship usually doesn't have a generated PK at all:

```
create table many_to_many
(
  one_id integer not null references table_one,
  other_id integer not null references other_table,
  primary key (one_id, other_id)
);
```

Comment: Therefore in PostgreSQL you can have rows which cannot be uniquely identified if the data is the same?

Comment: @YulePale: they can be identified by the primary key - and every table should have one (that's the basic principle of relational databases)

Comment: Therefore so that I can uniquely identify rows in PostgreSQL I need to explicitly tell PostgreSQL to create a unique id for every row?

Comment: When you say "and every table should have one", do you mean that it be made by PostgreSQL or that the coder should make one for every table?

Comment: @YulePale: no, you don't need to generate a unique ID if your data model doesn't need one. If you have a perfectly fine natural primary key that can be derived from your business data, then you don't need a generated primary key. Defining the primary key is one of the first steps in relational database design.

Comment: I think I understand now. PostgreSQL does not automatically generate a unique id like MongoDB does. But you can set it to if you want to? Or set any other field to be the primary key?

Answer (score 3):

@YulePale, moving to an environment with different rules is always kind of...tiring. They claim it's good for your brain, but learning a new paradigm is not a one day thing.

I'm responding because you've been asking variations of "in PostgreSQL you can have rows which cannot be uniquely identified if the data is the same?" Fair question, but it's important to think of this as a **feature**. Think of it in plain language terms, how *do* you distinguish things the are the same? They're indistinguishable, that's what being the same means.

Kind of the whole point in a relational database is to *not* have identical rows. Imagine that you have two documents that are exactly the same and you store them in two rows. In what way are they different? There's nothing about them that is different. So why do you have two rows? If there's additional information to distinguish them, then that's likely something to have in the row too. Maybe they came from different sources, so you store a path along with each document.

Figuring out what **in the data** uniquely identifies each row is the starting point for table design. It might be one "natural" field, but that's pretty rare. It might be a combination of fields.

It is commonplace to generate an ID (either a sequential number or a UUID) as a *convenience*. But bolting a unique number onto identical rows is a bad plan.

```
1 Don Perkins 123 Main St Waltham MA
2 Don Perkins 123 Main St Waltham MA
```

That ID at the front makes the rows unique, but the data isn't unique. Pretend that there really is only one Dan Perkins at that address. You've now got bad data. This kind of thing always ends in tears.

The Mongo paradigm and relational database design are different. You'll do yourself a favor to try and come to grips with relational design. Then, you can really exploit the power of a tool such as Postgres. Foreign keys, `JOIN`, and `CHECK` constraints are likely going to be your friends.

I don't know where you will find them, but checking in with people who have moved from Mongo to an RDBMS might be pretty helpful for you during the transition. I don't know Mongo, but there are lots of people who know both Mongo and Postgres. In fact, an important Postgres contributor is also behind a tool you might find of interest?

https://www.torodb.com/

I just looked it up, and it sounds like MongoDB generates a base-12 semi-random number for row IDs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

If you like that sort of thing, a good bet in Postgres would be a 16 byte UUID. Note that there is *no* timestamp data recoverable from a V4 UUID. If you need timestamps, you should add a column for those too.

Both of these columns can be set to auto-generate values when you create your record, right in the table's definition. You've already had a bunch of answers with samples.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was mostly confused about the id generation part. Now that I understand it I am finding SQL, most of the part, easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Every database has unique identifiers for each row.  Such identifiers are needed, for instance, for indexes on other columns so they can be referenced.

Postgres actually has a variety of internal ids.  [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) is a reference page for them.

That said, I think your question is whether Postgres automatically makes such an id available for use by users.  Let me answer that with a "no", although you can access some of the ids.

However, it is very simple to create one for any table where you need it.  Here are two common methods:

```
table_id serial primary key
table_id int generated always as identity primary key
```

Comment: Therefore so that I can uniquely identify rows in PostgreSQL I need to explicitly tell PostgreSQL to create a unique id for every row?

Comment: "*Every database has unique identifiers for each row.*" are you sure about the "every" part? To my knowledge MySQL does not have that. If I'm not mistaken MySQL puts all columns of a primary key into the index page. (I am not sure about SQL Server but I think it's similar at least with clustered indexes)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . How would the database be able to create an index on a table with no primary key?  The "unique identifier" might be a combination of table space id, page id, and offset on the page, but that would still be a unique id.  The rows *have* to be addressable to support certain SQL functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to generate an artificial id for your table if there is a natural primary key. You can use them also as foreign keys.

User id, email address, government issued personal id number or a nanosecond resolution timestamp are examples of such keys.

Comment: An email address is a very bad example of a natural primary key. Typically people have more than one, but what's even more important: they change.

Comment: If you are writing mail handling software, email address is a perfect candidate for a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't say email would identify a person - it identifies a mailbox. I want to have my webmaster@foo mails separate from my firstname@foo emails. And a car license plate might change (if you sell your car in Munch to someone in Austria) so it's not good for tracking vehicle lifetime service history but I still might use license plate number as primary key in a parking permit or car rental application.