# Are PostgreSQL autoicrementing id scalable?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL, I am coming from NoSQL.

[I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974078/does-postgres-automatically-generate-an-id-for-every-row/58974117?noredirect=1#comment104201721_58974117) that you need to make a unique id for you rows if you want to use unique ids. They are not automatically made by the database as it was in MongoDB. One way to do so is to create auto-incrementing ids.

Are PostgreSQL auto-incrementing id scalable? Does the DB have to insert a row at a time? How does it work?

**-----EDIT-----**

What I am actually wondering is in a distributed environment is there a risk that two rows may have the same id?

Comment: Built-in auto-incrementing should be scalable.  You can also use UUIDs if you don't want or need sequential ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there a benefit in creating sequential ids? Is it data you can use in some way or is used in some way as a common practice?

Comment: . . (1) It is common practice.  (2) It is generally easier for users to type in.  (3) They are shorter than other ids so they are better for indexes.  (4) They maintain insertion order.  These may or may not be important for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, autoincrement is atomic and scalable. In case some inserts fail, some ids can be missing from sequence but inserted are guaranteed to be unique.

Also, all primary keys don't have to be generated. See my answer to your first question.

Answer (score 2):

Autoincrementing columns that are defined as

```
id bigint PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('tab_id_seq')
```

or, more standard compliant, as

```
id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

use a [*sequence*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) to generate unique values.

A sequence is a special database object that can very efficiently supply unique integers to concurrent database sessions. I doubt that any identity generator, be it in MongoDB or elsewhere, can be more efficient.

Since getting a new sequence values accesses shared state, you can optimize sequences for high concurrency by defining them with a `CACHE` value higher than 1. Then each database session that uses the sequence keeps a cache of unique values and doesn't have to access the shared state each time it needs a value.